# sigsetjmp with global variable change?

Tags: c, unix

I'm using

```
int n; //global var.

int main() {

    if (sigsetjmp(jmpenv,0)) {
            n++;
            printf("%d", n);
    }
siglongjmp(jmpenv,1);

}
```

My question is: will this n keep increasing? Means that will sigsetjmp has effect on global variables? I know it will restore the local one :)

Thanks!

Comment: `setjmp()` only saves and restores function state. `n` is not inside the function.

Comment: BTW, testing by yourself would have been faster than asking!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[siglongjmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/siglongjmp.html) could be nearly understood as atomically and quasi-simultanously

- restoring the stack pointer registered at [sigsetjmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigsetjmp.html) time
- restoring the program counter registered at [sigsetjmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigsetjmp.html) time
- restoring other registers if they exist
- restoring the saved signal mask

your stack does not change between `sigsetjmp` and `siglongjmp` (no dynamic calling of function; we stay in the same [call frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)); so only the program counter (and other registers) changes, and that is like a `goto`

Hence your `n` (outside of the stack) is indefinitely incremented (till it overflows, then probably becomes `MIN_INT`)

BTW, you could look inside some free software implementation like [MUSL-libc's `siglongjmp.c`](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/signal/siglongjmp.c), it calls the assembly code [longjmp.s](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/setjmp/x86_64/longjmp.s)

<sup>Of course, things are very different if `n` was declared as a *local* variable (which the compiler might put in a register). I would imagine it is then [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), but I am not sure.</sup>